# Simulate a random quantum state time evolution in Qiskit Aqua

Tags: qiskit, programming, hamiltonian-simulation

I am trying to evolve a quantum state through a `PauliTrotterEvolution` in aqua and I'm trying to do so by initializing a random state, by using `random_statevector` from `qiskit.quantum_info`.

**My code:**

```
op=get_hamiltonian(-1,h) # a 4 qubit operator
evo_op=(t*op).exp_i()
evo_op=evo_op 

trotter_op=PauliTrotterEvolution(trotter_mode=Suzuki(reps=10,order=1)).convert(evo_op)
qinstance=QuantumInstance(backend=Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator"), shots=2048)
sampler=CircuitSampler(qinstance)

trotter_op=trotter_op @ StateFn(state)
results1=sampler.convert(trotter_op).primitive
```

**The error**

this returns the following error: `ValueError: Qiskit circuit Initializer cannot handle non-positive statevectors.` however, by the source code, the `Initializer` comes from `qiskit.extensions` which I believe is from this .py file ([file](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/e784e743018676a7d497ec7ab9b8b1265b65fa5a/qiskit/extensions/quantum_initializer/initializer.py#L33)) whose docstring states:

```
"""Complex amplitude initialization.
    Class that implements the (complex amplitude) initialization of some
    flexible collection of qubit registers (assuming the qubits are in the
    zero state).
    Note that Initialize is an Instruction and not a Gate since it contains a reset instruction,
    which is not unitary.
    """
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on the `Circuit_state_fn`. I added a Issue on the aqua github repo: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1276, thus in order to solve the problem you should pass the if statement on circuit_state_fn.py:

```
if not np.all(np.abs(statevector) == statevector):
            # TODO maybe switch to Isometry?
            raise ValueError('Qiskit circuit Initializer cannot handle non-positive statevectors.')
```